# How does Tomcat know which jar to choose for running a servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

In my project, **Apache Tomcat 8.5 context.xml** is configured as follows.

`<Context path="/helloWorld"  docBase="C:\projects\helloWorld\app" crossContext="false" debug="0" reloadable="false"/>`

C:\projects\helloWorld\app has a web-inf\lib folder which contains a **servlet.jar** along with the rest of the jars that the application needs.

This application is deployed to a Tomcat 8.5 web server and %TOMCAT_HOME%\lib folder also contains a **servlet-api.jar**.

The application is working as expected.

I have checked the two jars and servlet.jar contains the regular servlet api classes whereas tomcat's servlet-api.jar contains these regular servlet api classes along with many other servlet functionality related classes.

**Query:**
Since there are two jars for running a servlet viz, servlet.jar and servlet-api.jar, how does Tomcat know which jar to pick up when running a servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TLDR:

Tomcat will load its own version of the servlet API, because this is required by the JavaEE specification.

#### The long answer

JavaEE defines how classes are loaded and resolved.

Usually class-loaders are *parent-first* - i.e. trying to load classes from the parent class-loader and only if that fails, they try to load the class themselves.

But web apps have a *self-first* class-loader which loads classes from itself and only if it fails then they try to load from the parent. But there are a few exceptions:

- those self-first class-loaders cannot override JRE classes
- and they always do "parent-first" loading of JavaEE classes

You can read about that in more details on the [Apache Tomcat's docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

As long as the servlet api versions match there should not be any problems. But if your servlets are compiled against a different api version, for instance they are compiled using Servlet v4, but you try to use them in a Servlet v3  environment you will get runtime errors

Comment: So, in my application, the Tomcat's servlet-api.jar classes are loaded?

Comment: @Sara that's correct